# How do I read the rest of iTunesConnect Resolution Center messages?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm having trouble reading iTC resolution messages in their entirety.  On iTunesConnect, the messages on the left (in blue box) stop in the middle of the sentence and leave off the main point of the sentence.  This has never been a problem before.

Obvious things like clicking on the message, the badge number, or the link that says "1 unresolved issue" do not display the rest of the message.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks,

Eli

[Screenshot from iTunesConnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdZEc.png)

Comment: Did you try Safari ?

Comment: Yes, and Chrome. Used to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I had trouble too. If you put your mouse just above the Reply box on the right you will find that you can scroll in that area to expose the full message.